# How do I return an object in JAX-RS as YAML using Jackson in Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I created a Quarkus project using https://code.quarkus.io (with RESTEasy Jackson extension), a Greeting class defined as:

```java
public class Greeting {

    private final String message;

    public Greeting(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

And a JAX-RS endpoint to return it as YAML, so I wrote the following code:

```java
@Path("/greeting")
public class GreetingResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/yaml")
    public Greeting hello() {
        return new Greeting("hello");
    }

}
```

I also added the following dependency to my Quarkus project to return YAML:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-yaml-provider</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

However when I hit the endpoint, the following error is shown:

```
2020-05-22 10:55:55,693 ERROR [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (executor-thread-1) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: class org.acme.sample.Greeting of content type: application/yaml; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

What's the recommended way to fix this?

Comment: ...did somebody solve this? I have the same problem with a POST endpoint - no way to figure out how to read a YAML. JSON is no problem. 
btw - also having problems with the Tests using RestAssured and sending YAML (JSON no Problem)

Comment: Have you tried the answer below?

Comment: yes - but this is not helping. No way - strange, because with Json it worked out of the box. I will post here if I find out.

Comment: yes! it worked. Issues I had: `application.properties` at the wrong place. `mime-type` mismatch. Problems with `curl` command. haha. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Quarkus 3.x, you need to use the Jackson provider for Jakarta-RS dependency instead:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-jakarta-rs-yaml-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then add the following in your application.properties:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.yaml.group-id=com.fasterxml.jackson.jakarta.rs
quarkus.index-dependency.yaml.artifact-id=jackson-jakarta-rs-yaml-provider
```

Comment: George - thanks a lot for explaining and even fixing my small reproducer project (even my bad yaml ). also my original project is now fixed on the newest Quarkus! 
This was fun - and thanks to you all for the wonderful work on Quarkus!

Answer (score 4):

Besides adding the dependency in your pom.xml, make sure to also add the following to your `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.yaml.group-id=com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs
quarkus.index-dependency.yaml.artifact-id=jackson-jaxrs-yaml-provider
```

Comment: Migrating from Quarkus 2.12 to 3.2 destroyed this feature (see below) :-( does anybody have an idea what changed?

Answer (score 0):

Migrating from Quarkus 2.12 to 3.2 destroyed this feature (see below) :-( does anybody have an idea what changed?

```
        Suppressed: jakarta.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: interface java.util.List<class ch.schumm.stunden.input.Tag> of content type: application/yaml
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.throwReaderNotFound(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you open an issue in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues with a small reproducer project?

Comment: @gastaldi I did one: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34817 
thanks a lot for looking at it! (it destroyed my fav application hehe)

Comment: See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76721863/862119